# Issue with exporting a class with standard mutex member

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17

I have a C++ class, which is exported from a dll. The class has a `std::mutex` member variable as given below

```
class WGTKERNELKERNELSERVICES_API CPSCalHelper
{
    mutex m_RampVoltageMutex;
};
```

I get the following compiler warning. I have tried to use the structure used for exporting template classes`EXPIMP_TEMPLATE template class WGTKERNELKERNELSERVICES_API shared_ptr<vector<double>>;`, which is not working with mutex. What should I do to correct this?

```
warning C4251: 'CPSCalHelper::m_RampVoltageMutex': class 'std::mutex' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'CPSCalHelper'
```

Comment: There were never any mutexes in the STL. You're talking about the C++ Standard Library, solely.

Comment: tl;dr: don't - find another way